# Selecting only the last string in a column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

So im trying to select only the last string in a column

here's an example of what im trying to do

i have a table with products and the products images are within folder\folder\folder with some having more folders than others and i want to just view the image file such as

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(FILE_PATH, '[\|\]', ' ') FROM PRODUCT;
```

I got this to just breakup the file path such as folder folder folder cars.img

but now i want to just grab the string cars.img using substr doesn't really help as some file paths are longer than others and the names of the img file are longer than others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely **can** do this just with `SUBSTR` and `INSTR`, and it will be faster (perhaps much faster) than any REGEXP based solution.

The key is "counting from the end of the string", which is done with *negative* values for the position argument.

```
select substr(file_path, instr(file_path, '\', -1) + 1) from product;
```

`instr(file_path, '\', -1)` will find the position of the "first" backslash **from the end** of the string. Then `substr` will read from the **next** position (that is why you have +1) and it will read to the end of the string (the default when you omit the third argument to `substr()`).

**Demo**:

```
with product ( file_path ) as (
       select 'c:\del\img.jpg'               from dual union all
       select '.\prog\total\another_img.gif' from dual union all
       select 'image.gif'                    from dual
     )
-- End of SIMULATED inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- SQL query begins BELOW THIS LINE.
select substr (file_path, instr(file_path, '\', -1)  + 1) as file_name
from   product
;

FILE_NAME
---------------
img.jpg
another_img.gif
image.gif
```

Comment: Thank you so much! and now i understand substr and instr too!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use a combination of the below:

```
LEFT(FieldName, 10) = SUBSTR(FieldName, 1, 10)
RIGHT(FieldName, 3) = SUBSTR(FieldName, -3)

INSTR( string, substring [, start_position [, th_appearance ] ] )
```

Hope that helps.

Ted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(filepath, '[^\]+$', 1, 1)
```